# Xslt array and / or loop

Tags: xslt

I have following question, basically i just would like to create a custom array, something like
- Yellow | Red | Green

And after loop through this items using for-each and printing the values, i created something like this:

```
        <xsl:variable name="Colors">
           <m>Yellow</m>
           <m>Red</m>
           <m>Green</m>
        </xsl:variable>
```

And then i try to loop on it:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="$Colors">

            <xsl:value-of select ="current()" />                
        </xsl:for-each>
```

But i get this error: Exrpession must evalutate to a node-set $Colors

Any idea, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 your variable contains a result tree fragment (RTF) and you can't do anything with it but use `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:value-of`. Fortunately most XSLT 1.0 processor support `exsl:node-set` or similar to convert a result tree fragment to a node set so you can use `<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($Colors)/m">...</xsl:for-each>`, where you then need to declare `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` in your stylesheet.

Comment: If you use `<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($Colors)/m"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:for-each>` then the three values should be output. If that does not work then there might be a default namespace declaration in scope in your stylesheet. You would need to change the variable declaration to `<xsl:variable name="Colors" xmlns=""><m>Yellow</m>...</xsl:variable>` to make sure the `m` elements are in no namespace and can be selected as `m` in XPath.

Comment: just another question, regarding this, for clarification: <m> is necessary to use to building an array or i can create an array differently?

Comment: You are not building an `array` as XSLT/XPath does not have any such data type. In XSLT 1.0 you are creating a result tree fragment which you then convert to a node-set. To structure your result tree fragment you indeed need to use elements (or more generally nodes). With XSLT 2.0 there is more flexibility as there you could define a sequence of strings with `<xsl:variable name="colors" select="'Yellow', 'Red', 'Green'"/>`.